# Where can I get the terminal version of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, console

Where can I get the terminal version of Ubuntu with only basic stuff like `sudo` and `apt`. I prefer to customize it with CUBIC.

Comment: What is "the terminal version of Ubuntu"? Do you mean the version of the specific terminal emulator you are using? Or do you mean the version of the Ubuntu operating system? Or maybe the version of the shell (e.g. `bash`) you are running? Or do you mean you want to install a version of Ubuntu that has no GUI elements?

Comment: "Or do you mean you want to install a version of Ubuntu that has no GUI elements?" - Yeah, this one.

Answer (score 3):

Install [Ubuntu Server edition](https://ubuntu.com/download/server). AFAIK it only installs console - check the [Installation Instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server) and [Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs). Even tho' it's labeled "Server" it should work as a desktop just as well.

Another option is installing a regular Ubuntu. I've not checked, but if the installer has a package selection, you can just skip installing DE.

A third option would be using the [Minimal installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). There are a few kinks, tho' - last version is 18.04 LTS; it's never been officially supported; and out-of-the-box it only supports BIOS installation. I'd imagine a knowledgeable user can iron out those wrinkles.

Comment: +1 for Ubuntu Server for this task.